# What is the logic behind using a trained classifier's gradients to synthesize controllable image?

Tags: neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks, image-generation

In the controllable image synthesis, we are manipulating a noise vector **z** such that our generator ( in our GAN model ) creates images that the desired feature exists. For instance, take the feature of "smiling". In order to learn how to change the **z** (noise) vector , the technique is described as following :

1. Train a classifier ( besides the GAN model, just a single discriminator neural networks as a classifier) that classifies an face image according whether there is a smiling person on the image or not.
2. Give the image generated by the GAN model with the initial noise ( say z<sub>1</sub>) to the classifier.
3. Compute gradients of the score with respect to z<sub>1</sub>. And finally Perform gradient ascent on z<sub>1</sub> vector in the direction of improving the score.

I cannot understand how to gradients are used to change the z<sub>1</sub> vector in  a way that it now leads the GAN model to create "smiling" faces, could you please help ?

Comment: It's unclear whether you're only interested in the GAN or some other model. Can you please edit your post to clarify this? I would recommend that you focus on a specific model.

Comment: What do you mean by "GAN or some other model", could you please explain a little bit I did not understand ? There is both a GAN model and another Discriminator model ( not the GAN's discriminator instead just a single discriminator neural network ) in the question.